# Why does this JSON POST post an empty file?

Tags: json, curl, terminal

I am trying to post the following JSON to a URL using cURL in Terminal:

```
[
    {
        "token": "ABCDEF",
        "templateId": "{1234-5678-9}",
        "senders": "null",
        "viewers": "null",
        "peoples": "null",
        "fields": {
            "Matter Name": "My test matter name",
            "Matter Number": "ABC123"
        }
    }
]
```

This is how I POST it in Terminal:

```
curl -v -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d docfile=@test.json https://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension
```

The Terminal output clearly says that *something* was posted but the part that confuses me is this excerpt from the output: `upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes`

Only 18 bytes were sent? My file is 218 bytes...Why is this file not being POSTed? What *is* being POSTed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `-d` switch. From the documentation:

> -d
>
> Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server... If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from.

What you are passing to the `-d` switch does not begin with "@", so it is being interpreted as actual data. You'll notice `docfile=@test.json` IS actually 18 bytes.

You need to change it from `-d docfile=@test.json` to `-d @test.json`.

Comment: That just gives me the error: [{"id":"669feb88-bfac-4624-b7f2-df47561fb1f1","unmatched":[]}]

Comment: Ok. That is a step in the right direction. But did my answer fix the issue addressed in your question, i.e. "Why is this file not being POSTed? What is being POSTed?" If so, maybe you should consider opening a new question to address the new problem you are having.

Comment: Oops. You are right. Thank you. The error still persist but curl no longer attempts to post the path name.

Comment: Here is the link to my new question detailing the error above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814024/what-causes-this-error-when-posting-json-with-curl